# In a pdf file, how to record the page, row, column where the modified text is located

Tags: java

Existing requirements: search for the specified text in the pdf file, replace the specified text, and record the page, row and column where the modified text is located.
I am using the spire jar package, which has implemented search and replacement. The number of pages can be recorded with api, but I don't know how to record the rows and columns. There are many on the website that use the coordinate method to locate.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //加载示例PDF文档
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();
        pdf.loadFromFile("D:\\Spire\\Input\\test05.pdf");

        //遍历文档
        for (int i = 0; i < pdf.getPages().getCount(); i++)
        {
            //获取所有页面
            PdfPageBase page = pdf.getPages().get(i);

            //查找指定文本
            PdfTextFindCollection textFindCollection;
            textFindCollection = page.findText("内容提要");

            //创建画刷、字体
            PdfSolidBrush brush = new PdfSolidBrush(new PdfRGBColor(Color.red));
            PdfTrueTypeFont font= new PdfTrueTypeFont(new Font("宋体",Font.PLAIN,12),true);

            //用新的文本替换原有文本
            Rectangle2D rec;
            for(PdfTextFind find: textFindCollection.getFinds())
            {
                rec = find.getBounds();
                System.out.println(rec);
                page.getCanvas().drawRectangle(PdfBrushes.getWhite(), rec);
                page.getCanvas().drawString("Coffee", font, brush, rec);

            }

        }

        //保存文档
        pdf.saveToFile("D:\\Spire\\OutPut\\Replace.pdf");
        pdf.close();
    }
```